# Dynamic text was not working now in my contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, dynamic-text

Dynamic text was not working now in my contact form7

Plugin used - https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

Below code was working fine few days back but it was not working now. it displays the same quoteticket.

```
/* Generate Quote Ticket */
function genTicketString() 
{
    $length = 8;
    $characters = "0123456789";
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) 
    {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
    }
    return $string;
}
add_shortcode('quoteticket', 'genTicketString');



/* short code added in my contact form 7 */

[dynamichidden ticket_id "quoteticket"]
```

Comment: Which version of CF7 are you using?

Comment: im using Contact form  7 --> Version 5.1.1